# Efficiently referencing a C array using inline assembly

Tags: assembly

Using Windows XP, gcc.

I have a C++ project with some inline assembly code.
The assembly code needs to reference a C array.
Because I am using inline assembly. I have to pass a pointer to the array into one of the registers. Unfortunately this robs me of a register I need for some complex calculations.

I would like to know if there is an inline assembly way to reference a C array without having to lose a register or pushing the pointer to the stack.  The reason I cannot use the stack is because I am relying on the stack to store other values because I don't have enough registers as it is.

Comment: You need to edit your question to specify what platform you're working on.

Comment: Added the platform info.

Answer (score 1):

Doing "complex calculations" in assembly code?  Sounds like a mistake.  Usually, the only reason to write in-line assembly code is when you need to use a machine instruction that is not supported by a compiler intrinsic.

You didn't say what compiler you are using.  The asm() statement in GCC is very powerful.  You usually can write an asm statement that references your local or global variables by name, and you let the compiler choose the register(s).

Comment: I should add that the reason I am short on registers is because the values are too large to fit into a 32bit register and thus are spread across multiple registers. The domain is encryption.

Answer (score 0):

You normally use esi or edi registers to store informations like that, so registers which aren't involved in calculations at all. (assuming you're working on x86)